# Simulating regular expressions with deterministic finite automata and the size of the alphabet

Tags: finite-automata

I'm currently working my way through the "Dragon Book" (Compilers: Principles, Techniques, & Tools) and I'm kind of stuck at the lexical analysis chapter, which uses DFAs (Deterministic finite automata).

A DFA is a two-dimensional array, the first dimension contains the state and the second the transition symbols. This means that every DFA state contains all the symbols of the language. The examples in the book use a small language (usually two symbols), and they make the following note at the end of the chapter: "since a typical lexical analyzer has several hundred states in its DFA and involves the ASCII alphabet of 128 input characters, the array consumes less than a megabyte".

However, for matching strings I want to match all characters, which means the entire character set, and a lot of input files use UTF-8 encoding. This causes the alphabet, and thus the size of the DFA, to rise enormously.

This is the point where I'm stuck. How are lexical analyzers, or regular expression simulators in general handling this?

Thanks!

Comment: A DFA doesn't *have* to be a two-dimensional array as described. There are other options for the data structure, as long as the algorithms are adjusted to match. One that comes to mind would be an array of size(alphabet) entries, each of which is a linked list (or map or other data structure) of (current_state, next_state) pairs. So you index on the current input character, not on the current state. Just make sure to understand that algorithmic costs for alternative implementations...

Comment: The amount of states is manageable, what I'm concerned about is the size of the alphabet.

Comment: Which is why an array indexed by the alphabet, with each entry containing a list of valid state transitions for that character of input, might be more efficient space-wise than an array of states containing transitions for each possible input. It might turn out that the algorithms become less efficient that way, but programming is about trade-offs, and exchanging memory consumption for algorithmic complexity and/or performance is one of the more common ones...

Comment: Now I get it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had an epiphany on this problem. In lexical analysis, about the only time you want to match characters beyond the ASCII range is while doing wildcard matching, like in strings or comments. Because these are only used in wildcards, and not individually, all the characters with a value of 128 or higher can be represented as a single 'other' value. The alphabet and DFA remain small this way, while I am still able to use transition tables and match the entire unicode charset.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [interesting tool](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa) that converts a regular expression to non-deterministic finite automata.

Comment: I know that one, it isn't able to produce a correct DFA though. For instance, use the regex `[a-z]*|hi`. The DFA has two edges from the root, `h` and `[a-z]`. The `h` occurs in both edges, which isn't allowed in a deterministic finite automaton.